# .load() is not working - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like this:

```
$('#message').load('conversation.php?link=projects/living room/room');
```

When I run this code, it says `"syntax error, unrecognised expression"` in error console in chrome.

But if I run the same code like this:

```
$('#message').load('conversation.php?link=projects/livingroom/room');
```

This will work fine. The only differece between these two lines is, in the first one there is a space in the work (living room) and in the second line there is no space in the word (livingroom).

What is happening here. Why .load() displays error when put space and no error with no space?

Answer (score 1):

If , as @Matt Ball points out in comments above, [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) has a special interpretation for the URL that you do not need, then I recommend replacing `$.load()` with something that better suits the requirements.  In this case,  a [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) that includes the proper callback is more appropriate to your needs.

In this case, it is clear that part of the problem is the url including spaces.

But the part of the URL that is including spaces is in the data parameters, which for better consistency and reliability ought to be supplied as parameters to your jQuery functions instead of trying to construct the URL from the parameters yourself.

```
$.get('conversation.php',
   {link: 'projects/living room/room'}, 
   function(data){ $('#message').html(data) }
 );
```